# Get the <!--more--> link text

Tags: plugin-development, read-more

How I can get the  link text is using WordPress?

By default is something like:

```
Read More <span class="meta-nav">→</span>
```

buy I want to get that value in a variable because some WordPress installation can have that value customized (using filter the_content_more_link) or in another language.

In resumen: what I need is to get from WordPress the text (the HTML code) that WordPress uses to replace the  when display a Post Content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use posts custom fields to store a custom *continue reading* text for each post, and then use that value in `the_content_more_link` filter. For example you might have a custom field with meta key of `continue_reading` to enable users to specify the custom Read More text, and use that value like:

```
add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'ad_contiue_reading_text',10,2);
function ad_contiue_reading_text($content_more_link, $read_more_text) {

    $post = get_post();
    $new_read_more_text = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'continue_reading', true);
    // .. or any text you want, for example:
    // $new_read_more_text = 'Discover More <span>&rarr;</span>';

    if($new_read_more_text) {
        $content_more_link = str_replace($read_more_text, $new_read_more_text, $content_more_link);
    }

    return $content_more_link;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is to get from WordPress the text (or HTML piece) that WordPress uses to replace the <!--more--> when display a Post Content

Comment: The text you want is passed as the second argument to the `the_content_more_link` filter (ie the `$read_more_text` in the above code) and there is no filter specific for that value. If you are developing a theme you can change that value by passing it directly to `the_content($read_more_text)`, but if you are writing a plugin I think you need to use the `the_content_more_link` filter to manipulate it.